# Could not load type "oro_collection": class does not exist.?

Tags: php, symfony-3.4, orocrm

I am using collections in orocrm symfony 3, but I am getting the following error
Could not load type "oro_collection": class does not exist.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [

                'entry_type' => AppraisalParameterRatingType::class,
                'required' => false,
                'entry_options'=> array(
                'data_class' => 'Hrroll\\Bundle\\AppraisalsBundle\\Entity\\AppraisalParameterRating'
                )
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: I don't see here 'oro_collection' type.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to Symfony 3 you should use FQCN instead of class aliases for form types.
For more details [Symfony 3.0 upgrade documentation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form)

So instead of `oro_collection` it should be CollectionType::class. Here is an example: [Oro/Bundle/ReminderBundle/Form/Type/ReminderCollectionType](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/9057436cfb4baea07a1cf7e5a0827b3a27ec600f/src/Oro/Bundle/ReminderBundle/Form/Type/ReminderCollectionType.php#L34)